# Como criar triggers no BD usando XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, trigger, xampp

Um grupo tem **N** eventos e cada evento tem **M** gastos.

1) A trigger abaixo deveria atualizar a última modificação feita no grupo quando um INSERT é feito na tabela de eventos. Por que não funciona?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_eventos AFTER INSERT ON eventos
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE grupos SET ultima_att = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE grupo_id = (
        SELECT grupo_id_ref FROM evento_pertence_grupo WHERE evento_id_ref = NEW.evento_id
    );
END
```

2) Tem como criar uma trigger para um INSERT, UPDATE e DELETE de uma só vez? Por exemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER faz_tudo AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON tabela
```

Comment: 2) Não tem como, cria uma trigger para cada evento.

Comment: Você não tem instalado o PHPMyAdmin ??

Comment: 1) Seria `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` no lugar de `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP `, a tabela `evento_pertence_grupo` não tem `N` registros para o mesmo evento? então deveria ter um `group by` ai

Comment: Eu tenho o PHPMyAdmin instalado sim.
O CURRENT_TIMESTAMP está funcionando pois eu o testei tirando a cláusula WHERE do UPDATE, mas com ela não há nenhuma atualização nos registros. Na verdade, tem N eventos para o mesmo grupo. Então você diz para colocar um GROUP BY grupo_id_ref ?

Comment: @GuilhermeBornia Sim, `group by grupo_id_ref`, a não ser que um evento tenha 2 grupos, dai em vez de ser `WHERE grupo_id =` tem que ser `WHERE grupo_id IN`

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!